# Liskov, optional and derivied classes

Tags: python, liskov-substitution-principle

I have a hierarchy of classes that starts with:

```
class Filter(ABC):
    pass

...

class SomeFilter(DerivedFromFilter):
    pass
```

Then I have a hierarchy of classes with a method with a parameter that is supposed to be an Optional of a Filter.

```
class User(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def filter_it(f: Optional[Filter]):
        pass

 ...

 class SomeUser(DerivedFromUser):
     def filter_it(f: Optional[SomeFilter]):
          pass
```

This fails Liskov substitution principle: mypy complains about Optional[SomeFilter] versus Optional[Filter].

The rest of the code is structured so that when a SomeUser is istantiated, then only a SomeFilter gets passed. Only the leaf classes of the two hierarchies are instantiated, and they are in a 1-to-1 relation (SomeUser with SomeFilter, SomeOtherUser with SomeOtherFilter). All the intermediate classes in the hiearchy basically just provide functionality for the leaf classes.

The usage avoids the issue, but I'd like to have an issue-free design.

I could avoid the design problem if I declared the filter_it method only in the leaf classes, but then I'd lose the design constraint that imposes the creation of that method, which is a design issue since the user code relies on every leaf implementing it.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I myself said the design has issues. That's why I'm asking for help in fixing it.

Comment: The Liskov substitution principle says that a subclass can be a substitute of a superclass. It's not clear in your description where that can't happen, i.e. where in your code do you expect a class like `DerivedFromUser` and can't pass in `SomeUser`?

Comment: To be clear, only the leaves are concrete types. And to answer your point, there's no case where I specify DerivedFromUser and I can't pass in SomeUser.
Mypy compains about the optional[SomeFilter] not being a subsitute for optional[filter].

Comment: What are `DerivedFromFilter` and `DerivedFromUser`? They aren't defined here. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: However, imagine you have a list hinted as `x : list[User]`. For any arbitrary element `x[i]`, I should be able to pass an instance of any subclass of `Filter` to `x[i].filter_it`. But if `x[i]` is actually an instance of `SomeUser`, its `filter_it` is restricted to instances of `SomeFilter`.

Comment: The argument of a method in a subclass can be *broadened*, but it cannot be narrowed. The opposite is true of its return value: you can narrow the return value, but you cannot broaden it.